# Android Studio - How to create a transparent view that displays above current view

Tags: android, xml, android-canvas, transparency, android-view

So I have one activity, with its own XML file, and I have separate view that only uses canvas and has no xml. Code is explained here, problem and question is below the code.

Heres the first view, that uses canvas do draw:

```
public class BallView extends View {
    public BallView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        ...//create Ball objects
     }
}
```

The ball object, that actually draws on the canvas:

```
public Ball(int xMax, int yMax) {
    bounds = new RectF();
    paint = new Paint();
    ...(initialize variables)
}

public void begin(Canvas canvas){
    bounds.set(...);
    paint.setColor(...);
    canvas.drawOval(bounds, paint);
}
```

Here's the activity that calls the above view:

```
public class CircleBounceScreen extends ActionBarActivity{
    View ballView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ballView = new BallView(this);
        setContentView(ballView);
        .... //do stuff
    }

    // some triggermethod
    public void trigger(){
        setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
        //fade the button in
        //wait for the button to be clicked
    }
}
```

Now, I have a button in the activity_main XML file

```
<LinearLayout
    ...alignment stuff >
    <Button android:id="@+id/restart_button"
        ...design stuff
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

After the ballView executes for some time, it lets the activity know through a listener. Heres what I want to happen; the ballView STAYS IN VIEW, just in the background, and the button in the XML file is displayed above it. This will allow the ballView(which will be essentially frozen) and the button able to be clicked.

I have looked all over stack overflow, and all the solutions use a transparent activity background (but then changing setContentView(activity_main) would wipe out the previous view and it wouldnt matter if transparent or not.) Or, they merely define everything in the same XML file so they can simply setContentView to that XML file and be good. Note that I cannot do that because one of my view uses Canvas and the other uses XML.

So how do I display 2 views at the same time, with one transparently below the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include the ball view in the XML?

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/restart_button"
        ...design stuff
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <com.packagename.BallView
        android:id="@id/ball_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the view you can do:

```
public class CircleBounceScreen extends ActionBarActivity{
    View ballView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .... //do stuff
    }

    // some triggermethod
    public void trigger(){
        // restart_button set visibility visible
        //fade the button in
        //wait for the button to be clicked
    }
}
```

You may need to add extra constructors to BallView to allow it to be inflated in the XML:

```
public class BallView extends View {
    public BallView (Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    BallView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    BallView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        ...//create Ball objects
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have the constructor: BallView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr); 

what does that mean or do? can I just rely on 1 constructor?

Comment: Thats best explained on Android Developers site. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: But AttributeSet allows you to define certain things in the XML e.g. Ball colour which you can then later setup in code. The way these constructors have been setup is that no matter which of the 3 you call the one with your setup will be called. As the first calls the second and the second calls the third. Notice the number of parameters on each.

Comment: Also, with the XML, do I still define the ballView the same way? How do I display it?

Comment: Can I just leave the XML the way you did it and just define all my variables in my BallView class the same way?

Comment: It should be displayed because you have included it in a similar way to the above. <com.packagename.BallView> will allow you to add layout params like android:layout_height="match_parent" to it

Comment: "As the first calls the second and the second calls the third. Notice the number of parameters on each."
How do they call each other if they're just calling super()??

Comment: Everything in your BallView can stay the same but you need to at least add the constructors. You just need include BallView in XML with the correct package name and it will display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75558/discussion-between-numan1617-and-joe-bob).